# fsck - what to do at the end?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, dependencies, fsck

I have Ubuntu 16.04 dual-boot installed (w/Windows 7) on a Dell Latitude 6420 Laptop.

Yesterday, after the update, it requested reboot, then would not reboot completely. It got up to the user login, then would freeze after I entered my password.  A couple times it also froze at the login, not allowing me to even enter a password.

After some reading, I attempted logging in "safe mode". First I experimented with logging into the first option (ending in "generic"). I could log in and use the machine with no problem.  But upon logging in as normal, it continued to freeze.

After doing some more reading, I repeated the process, this time choosing the option ending in "recovery mode".

From there I chose the option, fsck... it ran and provided me with information about missing dependencies on my swap partition.

[image: fsck error screenshot]

So now my computer and I are having a really awkward moment of silence. It is holding, exactly as you see in the screenshot, waiting for me to do something, I suppose. And I'm here waiting for it to indicate to me what I'm supposed to do next.

So I have 2 questions:

1. What do I do next?
2. How do I go about remedying the missing dependencies?  Or is fsck supposed to do this?

**Additional Info:**

'exit' worked to get me out of this screen, and back to the grub/recovery mode menu

From this menu, choosing root access, then entering 'sudo fsck -f /' at the prompt, produced this response:

[Root access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMlbO.jpg)

Then I rebooted. Normal boot still didn't work, so I rebooted again into the *generic* option. I ran the following:

`sudo blkid`

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="2C2A0DEA2A0DB23E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="f752fb6f-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows 7" UUID="5E98156C981543C5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="f752fb6f-02"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Swap" UUID="4c570f54-c0d4-44ac-a132-9517c64f0cff" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="f752fb6f-04"
/dev/sda5: UUID="4320c663-1161-4fe9-b5f8-ac72526376db" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="f752fb6f-05"`
```

`cat /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=4320c663-1161-4fe9-b5f8-ac72526376db /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=4c570f54-c0d4-44ac-a132-9517c64f0cff none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0`
```

`cat /etc/crypt*`

```
cryptswap1 UUID=ce2b005b-dea2-4808-86eb-71884dfeb5c4 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

**NOTE:** Whereas booting into generic worked normal *before*, I now have no internet. When I open the Network Settings, and try to switch on Wi-fi, it flips itself back off. It does not work on the Windows side either. Windows does boot up normally otherwise.

Then I rebooted with the Boot Disk, ran *gparted* and snapped this image:

[Partition Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Dxh.jpg)

**Update:**

With every reboot, I keep checking to see if I can log in normally. Before being able to implement the suggestions below, my machine booted normally, in normal mode, but still without wi-fi (I have not yet attempted to wire it into the modem directly)

While booted normally, I checked all of the following:

gparted (corrected)- all partitions that are supposed to be encrypted are. I will add photo here in a few.

`sudo blkid` (changed) - there is a new line at the bottom containing an UUID for cryptswap1 that wasn't there before:

```
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="System Reserved" UUID="2C2A0DEA2A0DB23E" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="f752fb6f-01"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows 7" UUID="5E98156C981543C5" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="f752fb6f-02"
/dev/sda4: LABEL="Swap" UUID="4c570f54-c0d4-44ac-a132-9517c64f0cff" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="f752fb6f-04"
/dev/sda5: UUID="4320c663-1161-4fe9-b5f8-ac72526376db" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="f752fb6f-05"
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1: UUID="e9166797-d813-4430-ab6e-d2f060ca59c5" TYPE="swap"
```

`cat /etc/fstab` - the same, no change.

`cat /etc/crypt*` - the same, no change.

So I could no boot in normally, so my immediate problem was remedied. I rebooted into grub and ran fsck again, and there were still the same dependency errors.

So I entered into the grub root prompt as directed below and made the suggested changes. It did not boot normally. In *generic* mode I was able to grab a screenshot of gparted. Now the home partition is encrypted, but not swap.

I then realized what direction @heynnema was going and noticed that new UUID in  `fstab` and reworked his instructions using that UUID. Now it boots normal AND all partitions are encrypted as they should be.

However, when I go back into grub and run `fsck`, the same dependency errors are still there.

I'm not sure if I should count this as solved. I do have full access of my computer (sans wi-fi), and have successfully exited the grub.

Are the dependency errors something I need to worry about?  I thought dependencies were parts of update files and such - is the content I was adjusting also considered dependencies?

(The wi-fi issue, I'll put in a different post)

The learning curve is steep...

**Update #2**
**Additional Info:**

`free -h`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7G        1.5G        712M        216M        1.6G        1.8G
Swap:           14G          0B         14G
```

`swapon -s`

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda4                               partition   15625212    0   -1
```

`sudo lshw -C network`

```
[sudo] password for : 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 04
       serial: d4:be:d9:24:ae:23
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=0.13-3 ip=192.168.1.201 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:25 memory:e6e00000-e6e1ffff memory:e6e80000-e6e80fff ioport:5080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:e6d00000-e6d03fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: wlp3s0b1
       serial: c0:18:85:76:83:d1
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=4.10.0-27-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

`dkms status` returned nothing

`rfkill list`

```
0: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**fsck after disabling swap**

imgur.com/a/bKL64 (it wont let me post any more links)
It does not even list any swap information.

**Update 3 Info**

`free -h`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7G        1.9G        649M        322M        1.2G        1.3G
Swap:           14G        3.5M         14G
```

`swapon -s`

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda4                               partition   15625212    3604    -1
```

`fsck` in grub menu produced same dependency errors.

I notice however, that in the `TIME` line, parts of the number match the UUID for the old cryptswap1 - but not an exact match. I kept it in case I needed to change it back.

`cat crypttab.old`

```
#cryptswap1 UUID=ce2b005b-dea2-4808-86eb-71884dfeb5c4 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

I looked in the /dev/disk/... that it indicates and found this:

```
Latitude-E6420:/dev/disk/by-uuid$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 120 Jul 27 22:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 120 Jul 27 22:03 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 27 22:04 2C2A0DEA2A0DB23E -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 27 22:04 4320c663-1161-4fe9-b5f8-ac72526376db -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 27 22:04 4c570f54-c0d4-44ac-a132-9517c64f0cff -> ../../sda4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  10 Jul 27 22:04 5E98156C981543C5 -> ../../sda2
```

It's like it's looking for something that's not there, but all of my partitions seem accounted for.

Comment: `fsck` is for checking and correcting error on partitions and the reason it didn't work is because apparently Ubuntu was installed with LVM/encryption. It has nothing to do with dependencies, two entirely different beast and both UNRELATED to your issue because: *First I experimented with logging into the first option (ending in "generic"). I could log in and **use the machine with no problem**.*

Comment: My swap is in a separate partition and is also encrypted. I'll be including the screenshots here in a few, as suggested below. Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets rerun `fsck`, and then gather some data...

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors

Now we gather some data...

- type `sudo blkid`
- type `cat /etc/fstab`
- type `cat /etc/crypttab`
- type `free -h`
- type `swapon -s`

Take picture and add them to your question and I'll take a look.

Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and start `gparted`. Take a current-window-only screenshot and add that to your question.

**Update #1:**

Somebody must have been repartitioning the HDD/SDD, yes? It looks a little strange. And the UUID for the swap partition isn't consistent in `blkid` and `cryptswap1`, and fstab looks like it has some erroneous character in it.

Get to the root prompt, as per above, and type:

```
sudo mount -o rw,remount / # to remount as r/w
```

In `/etc/fstab`...

```
sudo pico /etc/fstab
```

check that this line...

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0`
```

gets changed to...

```
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

Then in `/etc/crypttab`...

```
sudo pico /etc/crypttab
```

Change this line...

```
cryptswap1 UUID=ce2b005b-dea2-4808-86eb-71884dfeb5c4 /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

To this...

```
cryptswap1 UUID=4c570f54-c0d4-44ac-a132-9517c64f0cff /dev/urandom swap,offset=1024,cipher=aes-xts-plain64
```

Then reboot.

**Update #2:**

Something just doesn't look quite right. Important to answer all questions.

1. when booting, does it ask for a decryption password?
2. when you do the `fsck` (do it my way, not from the menu) does it show pass 1, pass 2, etc and then return you to the # prompt?
3. does it still show the problems with swap?
4. when did the wireless network problem start?
5. are you able to direct wire a working ethernet connection?

Show me:

```
free -h
swapon -s
sudo lshw -C network
dkms status
```

**Update #3:**

You didn't show me the output of the above 4 commands. Edit your question with this output BEFORE performing the rest of this update.

Boot in such a way so you can see the swap error messages. Copy down as much of the displayed UUID's as possible. Compare them to both the old, and the newer `sudo blkid` commands, looking for a match.

Temporarily we're going to disable swap and swap encryption so that we can see if it has any effect on the wireless problem (I don't think it will).

In `terminal`...

```
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Edit these lines and comment out the last two lines by placing a `#` in front of each line. (Remember to uncomment these lines later).

Change this:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=4c570f54-c0d4-44ac-a132-9517c64f0cff none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

To this:

```
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
#UUID=4c570f54-c0d4-44ac-a132-9517c64f0cff none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

Then rename this (remember to rename it back later):

```
sudo mv /etc/crypttab /etc/crypttab.HOLD
reboot
```

Check the wireless.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63051/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-fsck-what-to-do-at-the-end).